# Google Sheets API and Pandas. Inconsistent data length from the API

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using the google sheets API to get data which I then pass to Pandas so I can easily work with the data.

Let's say I want to get a sheet with the following data (depicted as a JSON object as tables weren't presented here well)

```
{
  columns: ['Name', 'Age', 'Tlf.' 'Address'],
  data: ['Julie', '35', '12345', '8 Leafy Street']
}
```

The sheets API will return something along the lines of this:

```
{
  'range': 'Cases!A1:AE999',
   'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
    'values': 
    [
            ['Name', 'Age', 'Tlf.', 'Address'],
      ['Julie', '35', '12345', '8 Leafy Street']
    ]
}
```

This is great and allows me to easily pass the column headings and data to Pandas without much fuss. I do this in the following manner:

```py
values = sheets_api_result["values"]
df = pd.DataFrame(values[1:], columns=values[0])
```

My Problem

If I have a Gsuite Sheet that looks like the below table, depicted as a key:value data type

```
{
  columns: ['Name', 'Age', 'Tlf.' 'Address'],
  data: ['Julie', '35', '', '']
}
```

I will receive the following response

```
{
  'range': 'Cases!A1:AE999',
   'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
    'values': 
    [
            ['Name', 'Age', 'Tlf.', 'Address'],
      ['Julie', '35']
    ]
}
```

Note that the length of the two arrays are not unequal, and that instead of `None` or `null` values being returned, the data is simply not present in the response.

When working with this data in my code, I end up with an error that looks like this

```sh
ValueError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns
```

So as far as I can tell I have two options:

1. Come up with a clever way to pad my response where necessary with `None`
2. If possible, instruct the API to return a null value in the JSON where null values exist, especially when the last column(s) have no data at all.

With regards to point 1. I think I can append `x` `None` values to the list where `x` is equal to `length_of_column_heading_array` - `length_of_data_array`. This does however seem ugly and perhaps there is a more elegant way of doing it.

And with regards to point 2, I haven't managed to find an answer that helps me.

If anyone has any ideas on how I can solve this, I'd be very grateful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, here is how I solved the issue.

First, we need to get all the data from the Sheets API.

```py
# define the names of the tabs I want to get
ranges = ['tab1', 'tab2']

# Call the Sheets API
request = service.spreadsheets().values().batchGet(spreadsheetId=document, ranges=ranges,)
response = request.execute()
```

Now I want to go through every column and ensure that each row's list contains the same number of elements as the first row which contains the column headings.

```py
# response is the response from google sheets API, 
# and from the code above. It contains column headings
# and data from every row.

# valueRanges is the key to access the data.
def extract_case_data(response, keyword):
    for obj in response["valueRanges"]:
        if keyword in obj["range"]:
            values = pad_data(obj["values"])
            df = pd.DataFrame(values[1:], columns=values[0])
            return df
    return None
```

And finally, the method to pad the data

```py
def pad_data(data: list):

    # build a new array with the column heading data
    # this is the list which we will return
    return_data = [data[0]]

    for row in data[1:]:
        difference = len(data[0]) - len(row)
        new_row = row
        # append None to the lists which have a shorter
        # length than the column heading list
        for count in range(1, difference + 1):
            new_row.append(None)
        return_data.append(new_row)
    return return_data
```

I'm certainly not saying that this is the best or most elegant solution, but it has done the trick for me.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea, maybe simpler look:

Get raw values

```
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=data_range).execute()
raw_values = result.get('values', [])
```

Then complete while iterating

```
for row in raw_values:
    row = row + [''] * (expected_length - len(row))
```